# Get object based on guid of object inside that object using web api querying?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, database

I'm trying to get an object returned if it contains object2 inside object1. object2 must have the same guid as the parameter taken in.

I have this so far which returns object1 based on object1's guid:

```
[Route("{id:guid}")]
    public Object1 GetOpenObject2(Guid id)
    {
        var object1 = _someRepository.Get(id);

        return object1
    }
```

Needs to return object1 if it contains object2 with the same guid as the one passed into the function. Any ideas how I can do this? I'm new to Web Api and MongoDB.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        try
        {
            object1= _someRepository.GetAll().First(c => c.Object2.Id == id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

had to use a try catch like this using First and GetAll.